# Four-way logarithmic plot

Tags: plotting

Say I have a dataset named "d"

```
d = {{0.02`, 0.0012590355605140609`}, {0.07`, 
0.03190107785291465`}, {0.12000000000000001`, 
0.1341664962650996`}, {0.17`, 0.36075980746436004`}, {0.22`, 
0.357927357108827`}, {0.27`, 0.7918189679330538`}, {0.32000000000000006`, 
0.9908662217648183`}, {0.37000000000000005`, 
1.326284520883634`}, {0.42000000000000004`, 
1.6667182988224543`}, {0.47000000000000003`, 2.786860204849679`}, {0.52`, 
2.93933750379339`}, {0.5700000000000001`, 
3.9366944327584346`}, {0.6200000000000001`, 3.134060239061052`}, {0.67`, 
3.4525830444631516`}, {0.7200000000000001`, 3.146161177105212`}, {0.77`, 
3.020376751028269`}, {0.8200000000000001`, 
4.675746764366013`}, {0.8700000000000001`, 6.218831558416226`}, {0.92`, 
5.912788886349729`}, {0.9700000000000001`, 6.083549243252543`}, {1.02`, 
5.698685465342156`}, {1.07`, 5.335045431412702`}, {1.12`, 
4.588645123940877`}, {1.1700000000000002`,
  4.836149753666741`}, {1.2200000000000002`, 4.731911635811709`}, {1.27`, 
4.3204281272371095`}, {1.32`, 3.8191496326978123`}, {1.37`, 
4.425577764542655`}, {1.4200000000000002`, 
4.202433760690466`}, {1.4700000000000002`, 4.345090612510468`}, {1.52`, 
4.943409063693237`}, {1.57`, 5.5220625859488255`}, {1.62`, 
6.159173390833452`}, {1.6700000000000002`, 
6.429250552258077`}, {1.7200000000000002`, 6.3412110427206345`}, {1.77`, 
6.444125949011322`}, {1.82`, 6.941306477251247`}, {1.87`, 
7.269850600160908`}, {1.9200000000000002`, 
7.4459650057643145`}, {1.9700000000000002`, 7.381768092485144`}, {2.02`, 
7.638145357784952`}, {2.0700000000000003`, 8.126256325553179`}, {2.12`, 
8.057667374122504`}, {2.17`, 8.860957231660683`}, {2.22`, 
9.731314285903778`}, {2.27`, 10.521063318290198`}, {2.3200000000000003`, 
11.202904736346488`}, {2.37`, 11.746558133012728`}, {2.4200000000000004`, 
12.1887799898985`}, {2.47`, 12.524874206169914`}, {2.52`, 
12.947505240273822`}, {2.5700000000000003`, 13.340677305210736`}, {2.62`, 
13.590186938026871`}, {2.6700000000000004`, 14.14787161554347`}, {2.72`, 
15.664058697389326`}, {2.77`, 16.665468696630878`}, {2.8200000000000003`, 
17.000850998774546`}, {2.87`, 16.647131946787326`}, {2.9200000000000004`, 
16.3859238348108`}, {2.97`, 15.982010112784831`}};
```

and I generate two datasets from "d":

```
v = {#[[1]], #[[2]]*2*\[Pi]/#[[1]]} & /@ d;
a = {#[[1]], #[[2]]*(2*\[Pi]/#[[1]])^2} & /@ d;
```

I can plot "d", "v" and "a" individually as follows:

```
ListLinePlot[#] & /@ {d, v, a}
```

However I want to combine these three datasets into a 4-way logarithmic plot. The x-axis of the 4-way plot corresponds to the first column of the datasets i.e. period. The y-axis corresponds to the second column of the "v" dataset, the +45-degree axis corresponds to the second column of "d" dataset, and the +135-degree axis corresponds to the second column of the "a" dataset. This type of plot is used to present the response spectrum in earthquake engineering. Can anyone help with this type of plot? An example is shown.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Epilog` and `FullGraphics` with `RotationTransform` do the main part of the visualization

```
shift = {1, -1} Log[2 π]/Sqrt[2];
scale = {1, 1}/Sqrt[2];
ao = {0.5, 50};
ListLogLogPlot[{0}, Axes -> False, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.01, 10}, {0.1, 100}}, Frame -> True, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["x axis", 16], Style["v axis", 16]}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 500,
 Epilog -> {
   GeometricTransformation[#, RotationTransform[π/4]] &@
         GeometricTransformation[#, TranslationTransform[shift]] &@
       GeometricTransformation[#, ScalingTransform[scale]] &@
     Join[
      List @@ FullGraphics@
        ListLogLogPlot[{0}, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> ao, 
         PlotRange -> {{0.0002, 200}, {0.1, 100000}}, 
         GridLines -> Automatic], {Text[Style["d axis", 16], 
        Log@ao + {0.7, -0.2} Log[10]], 
       Rotate[Text[Style["a axis", 16], 
         Log@ao + {-0.2, 0.7} Log[10]], -π/2]}] /. 
    Text[s__] :> Text[s, Background -> GrayLevel[1, 0.8]],
   AbsolutePointSize[6],
   ColorData[1][1], Point@Log@v
   }]
```

[image]

Some details:

- `shift` shifts the position of (1,1) point of the 45-degree plot.
- `ao` sets the axis origin of the 45-degree plot.
- `Log`s converts the logarithmic values to the linear `Graphics` coordinates.
- `ColorData[1]` sets colors to usual colors of `Plot`.
- `/. Text[s__] :> Text[s, Background -> GrayLevel[1, 0.8]]` set background of all text labels of the 45-degree plot to white with small transparency.
- Unfortunately it doesn't work in V10 due to bugs (in Linux at lest). I used V9 to plot it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer to a difficult plot problem. My apology for not being clear in my question. Because the three parameters are related through a = (2*pi/T)*v = (4*pi^2/T^2)*d, the 3 datasets can actually be plotted as just one line in the 4-way logarithmic plot. This may involve re-scaling the y, +45-degree and +135-degree axes to condense them into one line. I wonder plotting them as one line can be done.

Comment: @user11946 I adjusted the scale and the shift. It is a really nice property of this plot!

Comment: Wow - it runs perfect in MMA 9.0. This is exactly what I am looking for. I hope the plot issue gets resolved in the version 10 updates.